# Problema el webhook no actualiza mi BOT

Tags: php, webservice, whatsapp

Mi problema o inconveniente es que aparentemente al yo enviar un mensaje a mi numero de **whatsapp** proporcionado por **twilio** debería de actualizar mi **bot** alojado en un servidor con una url publica utilizando un **webhook**. Pero nunca se ejecuta ya que los mensajes que envió desde mi **tlf** nunca son leídos y menos respondidos.

Este es mi código:

```
use Twilio\Twiml;
require ('func_FB.php');
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

$response = new Twiml;
$mess = $_REQUEST['Body'];
$pick = rand(1,5);

//$BOT=new func_BOT();
//$BOT->Procesar($guess);

if (!in_array($mess, [1,2,3,4,5])) {
   $response->message("Hiya! I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 5 - try to guess it!");
} elseif ($mess == $pick) {
   $response->message("Yes! You guessed it!");
} else {
   $response->message("Nope, it was actually $pick - Pick a new number to play again!");
}
print $response;
```

No debería haber algún error ya que este código es un ejemplo de la [documentación](https://www.twilio.com/blog/php-twilio-whatsapp).

Mi [url publica](https://lateen-coal.000webhostapp.com/bot-whatsapp/BOT_MANDADOS.php), es la producida por mi servidor de prueba **000webhost**

Este mismo **url** lo coloque en la configuración de **sandbox** en la opción:**"A MESSAGE COME COMES IN"**.

Gracias y espero su respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Has puesto `print $response;` y cargas el autoload? Si has puesto todo tu código, te faltan esas dos cosas y el use

Comment: Amigo disculpe, pero si implemente las clases o si cargue el autoload y use, excepto que no lo coloque porque estaba en la parte superior y se me paso escribirlo, pero si los declare, ademas que trabajo en netbeans y este es muy temático con esos puntos. Gracias

Comment: Si ya has puesto todo el código, te falta el print

Comment: Ya coloque el print, pero ha este yo no le doy gran importancia ya que esto lo único que hace es imprimir la variable en pantalla.

Comment: El print es imprescindible ya que es la forma de responder según el tutorial que pusiste. ¿Has hecho lo de ```ngrok http 80```?

Comment: No amigo, no he aplicado el ngrok http ya que este software lo que permite es transformar una url local en publica, pero un host te debería de garantizar esto (¿creo?)

Comment: Tienes razón, me había quedado con que lo tenias en local. Lo único que podría faltarte es añadir la url al sandbox

Comment: Gracias no me había percatado de que había puesto un **print** ante del código que publique y por esto producía el error llamado error HTTP 11200.